# Mac no longer boots

Tags: mac, startup

I’ve been using my Mac all year without fear. On Tuesday I shut it down as I was going out of town. Today, I tried booting up my Mac and it won't boot.

I tried resetting PRAM and SMC, but no go. I did the command D thing, but no issues reported.

Comment: Which Mac do you have and which macOS is it running?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I’m going to jump out on a limb here and make the assumption that you’re probably a Chrome user and before you went away you updated Chrome.

If so, you're probably the victim of a Chrome updater bug and your issues are not related to your Apple hardware nor a bug with macOS.

***NOTE:*** If you're running Mac OS X El Capitan or later **and** have not disabled SIP, then this **will not** be the cause of your problem, in which case you'll need to skip this answer and investigate other causes!

To rectify this, you need to follow these steps:

1. Boot into recovery mode by using the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut upon powering up your Mac.
2. When you see the macOS Utilities window, go to the Utilities menu bar option and select Terminal
3. In terminal, enter the following commands one by one, followed by pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key (**NOTE:** If your Mac hard drive is not called `Macintosh HD` then you will need to change the first command below to reference the name of your hard drive)

   ```
   chroot /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
   rm -rf /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle
   mv var var_back
   ln -sh private/var var
   chflags -h restricted /var
   chflags -h hidden /var
   xattr -sw com.apple.rootless "" /var
   ```
4. Now reboot your Mac.

**Further reading:**

You may be interested in reading:

- [Issue 1007358: Keystone modifies /var](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1007358)
- [Chrome Update Impacts Some macOS Systems](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15235262)

Comment: How did you think of this, given the OP description of the problem?? The Chrome bug only affects systems with SIP disabled.

Comment: OMG! This freaking worked! You totally saved me!!

Comment: @lhf Yeah, like I said, I was going out on a limb with my answer. My thought process was as follows: Many Uni students use Chrome because of its integration with Google’s services and because many online Uni dashboards have some compatibility issues with Safari. That, along with the timing of two days ago meant that it lined up with the timing of the Chrome update. As an aside, SIP only needs to be disabled if the user is running El Capitan or later (obviously) so this issue can affect other systems. In this case we don’t have that info re the OP either way.

Comment: @lhf By the way, thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer to provide additional info to help other users decide if this applies to them.

Comment: @lhf the Chrome bug *also* affects systems that don't support SIP. I suspect the number of those is far higher than the number of systems with SIP disabled.

Comment: I wouldn't say that a user-mode application making the OS unable to boot isn't a bug in the OS, but at least there's a workaround :)

Comment: @Luaan It's not a user mode application. It's an updater with admin priviledges. And those by definition have to be able to ruin the OS. (You can make accidental damage less likely with ACLs on system files and things like SIP, but an administrator has the ability to disable those, otherwise he's not really an admin)

Comment: you might want to answer this too. .https://superuser.com/questions/1486781/chrome-renderer-using-over-100-of-cpu-on-mac-os#comment2242839_1486781 :)

Comment: well the commands to run were posted by google themselves. You can see their solution here if you expand https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15235262?hl=en.

Comment: I highly appreciate for such kind of solution. Keep on posting. This solution was even faster than Google Chrome fixing their bugs :D