# Mac Pro 2009 very hard to boot; shuts down randomly; fan spinning high

Tags: mac-pro, temperature

My Mac Pro from 2009 has been very hard to boot recently.

The procession is usually as follows:

- Will start to boot, shuts down, fans start spinning at maximum speed, for multiple times
- Will get to login screen, instant shut down, fan starts spinning at maximum speed
- Will be able to log in, instant shut down, fan starts spinning at maximum speed

It always goes through this progression. At times, the Mac will still shut down randomly after that, but will boot up in one go after that shutdown.

It has been getting worse and worse. Initially, it wouldn't crash. Then it would start crashing randomly. Then it would be harder to boot.

Diagnostic reports show nothing, temperature sensors all seem normal when the computer is running. The fan also doesn't spin fast before these shutdowns. SMC reset doesn't help.

EDIT: after a while, I found what is likely to be the cause of the issue.

```
2019-10-22 21:29:49 Kernel Panic (18 times)
    Details:
        panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800038776f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f80c62
        6de, type 14=page fault, registers:
    3rd party kernel extensions:
        com.nvidia.NVDAStartupWeb
        com.nvidia.web.GeForceWeb
        com.nvidia.web.NVDAGM100HalWeb
        com.nvidia.web.NVDAResmanWeb
        com.parrotgeek.SIPManager
        org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
        org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
        org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
        org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB

2019-10-22 16:40:53 mdworker - Memory (3 times)
    Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker

2019-10-21 07:19:09 com.apple.WebKit.WebContent - Memory (3 times)
    Executable: /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent

2019-10-21 00:33:39 helpd - Memory (4 times)
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HelpData.framework/Versions/A/Resources/helpd

2019-10-20 18:57:24 WindowServer - High CPU Use (2 times)
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer

2019-10-20 03:11:48 spindump - Crash
    Executable: /usr/sbin/spindump
    Details:
        Assertion Failed -[SPSampledProcess requireHIDEvent:]_block_invoke_2 S
        PProcessEvent.m:839 _hidEventSem == NULL
        abort() called

2019-10-19 04:02:37 Runner.app - Crash (3 times)
    Executable: /Users/***/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B678EE85-7528-4857-9AC2-FD2268C856E9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/499D7ED6-B35E-40C0-A9C5-20A24408F686/Runner.app
    Details:
        abort() called
        CoreSimulator 581.2 - Device: iPhone XR - Runtime: iOS 12.1 (16B91) -
        DeviceType: iPhone Xʀ
```

Comment: Did you run the full AHT tests? When was the last time the PRAM battery was changed? If you can't remember, then that would be first thing to do.

Comment: this sounds somewhat like the SIP-Chrome bug: https://www.techradar.com/news/faulty-google-chrome-update-makes-mac-pros-in-hollywood-grind-to-a-halt

Comment: Ouch - same announcement, not behind a paywall nag - https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15235262?hl=en

Comment: we have that on our site too :) [Mac no longer boots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371021/mac-no-longer-boots/371022#371022)